# Unable to read data from USB hid device with android in host mode

Tags: android, usb, hid

I'am able to connect to device and ask device specifications:

specs:

```
Model: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
ID: 1002
Class: 0
Protocol: 0
Vendor ID 1155
Product ID: 22352
Interface count: 1
---------------------------------------
*****     *****
Interface index: 0
Interface ID: 0
Inteface class: 3 USB_CLASS_HID
Interface protocol: 0
Endpoint count: 2 
++++   ++++   ++++
Endpoint index: 0
Attributes: 3
Direction: 128 (device to host)
Number: 1
Interval: 1
Packet size: 64
Type: 3 USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT (interrupt endpoint)
++++   ++++   ++++
Endpoint index: 1
Attributes: 3
Direction: 0 (host to device)
Number: 1
Interval: 1
Packet size: 64
Type: 3 USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT (interrupt endpoint)
No more devices connected.
```

I'am also able to send data from host to device, using this method:

```
    int bufferDataLength = mEndpointOut.getMaxPacketSize();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferDataLength + 1);
    UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();

    buffer.put(DataToSend);

    request.initialize(mDeviceConnection, mEndpointOut);
    request.queue(buffer, bufferDataLength);
    try
    {
        if (request.equals(mDeviceConnection.requestWait()))
        {
            // Read an analyze the incoming data here
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(byteBuffer, 0, buffer.remaining());
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error sending data: " + ex.toString());
    }
    return false;
```

But i'am not able to read from device, i've tested several methods without success..

for example this doesn't work:

```
    int bufferDataLength = mEndpointIn.getMaxPacketSize();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferDataLength + 1);

    //Make a request
    UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
    request.initialize(mDeviceConnection, mEndpointIn);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferDataLength);
    //For IN endpoints, data is read into the buffer
    request.queue(buffer, bufferDataLength);
    //This blocks until the request is successful
    //Make sure the request that finished is the one you need
    if (mDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request) {
     // Read an analyze the incoming data here
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(byteBuffer, 0, buffer.remaining());
    }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the correct endpoint? The In Request looks fine to me

Comment: Yes I think it's the correct end point, anyway a tried with both endpoint but i had no luck..

Comment: How are you polling the In Endpoint for new messages? Can you share the read thread? Have you referred to the USB Missile Launcher example from the Android SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problems using this class, i'm answering to my my question hoping it can help someone else:

```
/**
 * This class is used for talking to hid of the dongle, connecting, disconnencting and enumerating the devices.
 * @author gai
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
public class HidBridge {
    private Context _context;
    private int _productId;
    private int _vendorId;


    //private HidBridgeLogSupporter _logSupporter = new HidBridgeLogSupporter();
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
            "com.example.company.app.testhid.USB_PERMISSION";

    // Locker object that is responsible for locking read/write thread.
    private final Object _locker = new Object();
    private Thread _readingThread = null;
    private boolean _runReadingThread = false;
    private String _deviceName;

    private UsbManager _usbManager;
    private UsbDevice _usbDevice;

    // The queue that contains the read data.
    private Queue<byte[]> _receivedQueue;

    /**
     * Creates a hid bridge to the dongle. Should be created once.
     * @param context is the UI context of Android.
     * @param productId of the device.
     * @param vendorId of the device.
     */
    public HidBridge(Context context, int productId, int vendorId) {
        _context = context;
        _productId = productId;
        _vendorId = vendorId;
        _receivedQueue = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
    }

    /**
     * Searches for the device and opens it if successful
     * @return true, if connection was successful
     */
    public boolean OpenDevice() {
        _usbManager = (UsbManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = _usbManager.getDeviceList();

        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        _usbDevice = null;

        // Iterate all the available devices and find ours.
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
            if (device.getProductId() == _productId && device.getVendorId() == _vendorId) {
                _usbDevice = device;
                _deviceName = _usbDevice.getDeviceName();
            }
        }

        if (_usbDevice == null) {
            Log("Cannot find the device. Did you forgot to plug it?");
            Log(String.format("\t I search for VendorId: %s and ProductId: %s", _vendorId, _productId));
            return false;
        }

        // Create and intent and request a permission.
        PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        _context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

        _usbManager.requestPermission(_usbDevice, mPermissionIntent);
        Log("Found the device");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the reading thread of the device.
     */
    public void CloseTheDevice() {
        try 
        {
            StopReadingThread();
            _context.unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            Log("Error happend while closing device. Usb reciver not connected.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts the thread that continuously reads the data from the device. 
     * Should be called in order to be able to talk with the device.
     */
    public void StartReadingThread() {
        if (_readingThread == null) {
            _runReadingThread = true;
            _readingThread = new Thread(readerReceiver);
            _readingThread.start();
        } else {
            Log("Reading thread already started");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stops the thread that continuously reads the data from the device.
     * If it is stopped - talking to the device would be impossible.
     */
    public void StopReadingThread() {
        if (_readingThread != null) {
            // Just kill the thread. It is better to do that fast if we need that asap.
            _runReadingThread = false;
            _readingThread = null;
        } else {
            Log("No reading thread to stop");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write data to the usb hid. Data is written as-is, so calling method is responsible for adding header data.
     * @param bytes is the data to be written.
     * @return true if succeed.
     */
    public boolean WriteData(byte[] bytes) {
        try
        {
            // Lock that is common for read/write methods.
            synchronized (_locker) {
                UsbInterface writeIntf = _usbDevice.getInterface(0);
                UsbEndpoint writeEp = writeIntf.getEndpoint(1);
                UsbDeviceConnection writeConnection = _usbManager.openDevice(_usbDevice); 

                // Lock the usb interface.
                writeConnection.claimInterface(writeIntf, true);

                // Write the data as a bulk transfer with defined data length.
                int r = writeConnection.bulkTransfer(writeEp, bytes, bytes.length, 0);
                if (r != -1) {  
                    Log(String.format("Written %s bytes to the dongle. Data written: %s", r, composeString(bytes)));
                } else {
                    Log("Error happened while writing data. No ACK");
                }

                // Release the usb interface.
                writeConnection.releaseInterface(writeIntf);
                writeConnection.close();
            }

        } catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log("Error happend while writing. Could not connect to the device or interface is busy?");
            Log.e("HidBridge", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if there are any data in the queue to be read.
     */
    public boolean IsThereAnyReceivedData() {
        synchronized(_locker) {
            return !_receivedQueue.isEmpty();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Queue the data from the read queue.
     * @return queued data.
     */
    public byte[] GetReceivedDataFromQueue() {
        synchronized(_locker) {
            return _receivedQueue.poll();
        }
    }

    // The thread that continuously receives data from the dongle and put it to the queue.
    private Runnable readerReceiver = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (_usbDevice == null) {
                Log("No device to read from");
                return;
            }

            UsbEndpoint readEp;
            UsbDeviceConnection readConnection = null;
            UsbInterface readIntf = null;
            boolean readerStartedMsgWasShown = false;

            // We will continuously ask for the data from the device and store it in the queue.
            while (_runReadingThread) {
                // Lock that is common for read/write methods.
                synchronized (_locker) {
                    try
                    {
                        if (_usbDevice == null) {
                            OpenDevice();
                            Log("No device. Recheking in 10 sec...");

                            Sleep(10000);
                            continue;
                        }

                        readIntf = _usbDevice.getInterface(0);
                        readEp = readIntf.getEndpoint(0);
                        if (!_usbManager.getDeviceList().containsKey(_deviceName)) {
                            Log("Failed to connect to the device. Retrying to acquire it.");
                            OpenDevice();
                            if (!_usbManager.getDeviceList().containsKey(_deviceName)) {
                                Log("No device. Recheking in 10 sec...");

                                Sleep(10000);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        try
                        {

                            readConnection = _usbManager.openDevice(_usbDevice); 

                            if (readConnection == null) {
                                Log("Cannot start reader because the user didn't gave me permissions or the device is not present. Retrying in 2 sec...");
                                Sleep(2000);
                                continue;
                            }

                            // Claim and lock the interface in the android system.
                            readConnection.claimInterface(readIntf, true);
                        }
                        catch (SecurityException e) {
                            Log("Cannot start reader because the user didn't gave me permissions. Retrying in 2 sec...");

                            Sleep(2000);
                            continue;
                        }

                        // Show the reader started message once.
                        if (!readerStartedMsgWasShown) {
                            Log("!!! Reader was started !!!");
                            readerStartedMsgWasShown = true;
                        }

                        // Read the data as a bulk transfer with the size = MaxPacketSize
                        int packetSize = readEp.getMaxPacketSize();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[packetSize];
                        int r = readConnection.bulkTransfer(readEp, bytes, packetSize, 50);
                        if (r >= 0) {
                            byte[] trancatedBytes = new byte[r - 1]; // Truncate bytes in the honor of r

                            int i=0; 
                            for (byte b : bytes) {
                                if (i > 0)
                                    trancatedBytes[i - 1] = b;
                                i++;
                            }

                            _receivedQueue.add(trancatedBytes); // Store received data
                            Log(String.format("Message received of lengths %s and content: %s", r, composeString(bytes)));
                        }

                        // Release the interface lock.
                        readConnection.releaseInterface(readIntf);
                        readConnection.close();
                        } 

                    catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Log("Error happened while reading. No device or the connection is busy");
                        Log.e("HidBridge", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch (ThreadDeath e) {
                        if (readConnection != null) {
                            readConnection.releaseInterface(readIntf);
                            readConnection.close();
                        }

                        throw e;
                    }
                }

                // Sleep for 10 ms to pause, so other thread can write data or anything. 
                // As both read and write data methods lock each other - they cannot be run in parallel.
                // Looks like Android is not so smart in planning the threads, so we need to give it a small time
                // to switch the thread context.
                Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    };

    private void Sleep(int milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if(device != null){
                          //call method to set up device communication
                       }
                    } 
                    else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "permission denied for the device " + device);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Logs the message from HidBridge.
     * @param message to log.
     */
    private void Log(String message) {
        //LogHandler logHandler = LogHandler.getInstance();
        //logHandler.WriteMessage("HidBridge: " + message, LogHandler.GetNormalColor());
        Log.i("HidBridge: ", message);
    }

    /**
     * Composes a string from byte array.
     */
    private String composeString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b: bytes) {
            builder.append(b);
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the way you used the above class to solve your problems. I am facing the same issue on my end... [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56808341/658259)